# Url with tenant id on it, alternatives to pass it as a param?

Tags: java, url-rewriting, multi-tenant

I'm trying to map an url like **www.host.com/{tenant-id}/home** to something like **www.host.com/home.xhtml?tenantId={tenant-id}** where "tenant-id" is the name of the tenant that is using the app, and could be almost anything.

After some research I found many alternatives, but none of them convinces me. I'll list the alternatives so maybe I can help anyone and get some feedback on missing alternatives at the same time.

Furthermore, my app is written in java.

- Pretty Faces (or Rewrite). http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/
- Htmleasy (Resteasy) https://github.com/voodoodyne/htmleasy
- A filter, handmade.
- URL rewrite trough proxy (Apache / HaProxy)

I tried pretty faces and get it to work. But I'm concerned about some performance issues with high load. I don't know what PF do internally, and I'm afraid that processing every request and applying filters could be bad.

A handmade filter, would be impossible to maintain.

Does anyone have experience with Htmleasy?

Do you know any other alternative?

Thanks in advance
Cristian.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I can get a right approach for Java. I am from a .Net background. If this were given to me, i would like to create a `httpmodule` that intercepts each request and then translates the uri accordingly. However, it will not be required to enable the tenant code in the uri for each request, I would suggest that you initially create a tenant context from within your app and then use it for tenant identification.

This will be far more secure and easy than handling the uri changes per request.

HTH